# Implement the Levensthein-distance in F#

Tags: math, recursion, f#

Is there anyone who can help me implement the Levensthein-distance in F# using recursion? The distance is defined as the minimum number of edits on character level, which are essential for the string a to be identical to the string b. Mathematically the Levensthein-distance *leven(a,b)* between two characterstrings *a* and *b* be defined as *lev_ab(|a|,|b|)* where *|a|* and *|b|* refers to the lengths of *a* and *b* and the function is defined as follows:
[image]

Where *1_(ai not bj)* refers to the indicatorfunction which is 1, when *a_i not b_j* and 0 otherwise.

Comment: I used it in here https://github.com/gusty/Bitpart/blob/master/Bitpart.Server/Lib.fs#L8

Comment: What have you already tried? Where is the blocking issues? SO is not a "write code for free" site. This is the site to help people who already did most of the work but hit a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few years ago I blogged upon implementing `Levenstein distance` in F#, where I've considered and compared few implementation approaches, including recursion. The [post](https://infsharpmajor.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/if-google-would-be-looking-to-hire-f-programmers-part-7/) contains code snippets and performance analysis.